# React state is null inside of return

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern, react-state

I have the following code and every time I try to access the state inside of the return I got a

> TypeError: Cannot read property '#property' of null

```
import React, {useEffect, Fragment} from 'react'
import {Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {getProduct} from '../../actions/produto'


const Product = ({getProduct, match, produto: {produto}}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        getProduct(match.params.id);
    }, [getProduct, match.params.id]);

    console.log(produto);
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    {produto.name}
                </Col>                
            </Row>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

Product.propTypes = {
    getProduct: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    produto: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({
    produto: state.produto
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getProduct})(Product)
```

However if I console.log(produto) before the return I can get the real state value.
The state has the correct value until I try access {produto} inside the return statement. When I do that it changes to null.
Can someone explain me why does this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please add your reducers code?

Comment: The only reason I could see is getProduct is setting the produto again as null

Comment: Maybe some changes in  match.params.id happens and then useEffect calls again

Comment: @MaheshSapkal I belive that too, but I don't know why is doing that

Comment: @Tatiana I've checked. When I try to render {produto} the useEffect is not being called. That's why {produto} is null.But this only happens when I try to render it/.

Answer (score 0):

This is my reducer

```
   import {
        GET_PRODUCT,
        GET_PRODUCTS,
        GET_PRODUCT_ERROR,
        PRODUCT_LOADED
    } from '../actions/types'

    const initialState = {
        produto: null,
        produtos: []
    }

    export default function(state = initialState, action){
        const {type, payload} = action;
        switch(type){
            case GET_PRODUCT:
            case PRODUCT_LOADED:
                return{
                    ...state,
                    produto: payload
                }
            case GET_PRODUCTS:
               return {
                ...state,
                produtos: payload
               }
            case GET_PRODUCT_ERROR:
                return{
                    ...state,
                    produto: null,
                    produtos: null
                }
            default: 
                return state
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [React state is null inside of return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235685/react-state-is-null-inside-of-return/62236123#comment110069110_62235685)

@mo-ismat said: the reason this happens is because the api call is asynchronus, it doesn't populate the state immediately, so the render happens first and tries to read .current from the initial state null

That's actually worked. I added a conditional before rendering the state `{produto && produto.name}` value and it worked.

Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: Right link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263525/useeffect-not-being-called-and-not-updating-state-when-api-is-fetched